# Spring data repository does not save data in an Many to Many relation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm creating a data model that allows me to manage invoices. the problem I'm having is when I try to consume the service via @POST.  Everything is correct, even when I verify in the database and there are no records of the foreign key invoice_id

**Error here:**

[image]

[image]

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice")
data class Invoice (

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Int? = 0,

        val createdAt: LocalDateTime? = LocalDateTime.now(),
        val updatedAt: LocalDateTime? = LocalDateTime.now(),

        val nombre: String? = "",
        val direccion: String? = "",
        val telefono: String? = "",

        var order_total : Int? = null,

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoice", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
        @JsonManagedReference
        val invoiceItems: List<InvoiceItem>? = mutableListOf()

)
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
data class Item(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long? = null,
        val name: String? = null,
        val description: String? = null,
        val price: Int? = null,
        val img_url: String? = null,
        val createdAt: LocalDateTime? = LocalDateTime.now(),
        val updatedAt: LocalDateTime? = LocalDateTime.now(),

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
        @JsonBackReference
        val items: List<InvoiceItem>? = mutableListOf()

        )
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice_item")
data class InvoiceItem(

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Int? = 0,

        val quantitiy: Int? = 0,

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn (name = "invoice_id")
        @JsonIgnore
        val invoice: Invoice? = null,

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn
        val item: Item? = null

)
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 08 Aug 2020 04:35:13 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "id": 5,
  "createdAt": "2020-08-07T23:35:13.2283331",
  "updatedAt": "2020-08-07T23:35:13.2283331",
  "nombre": "Z",
  "direccion": "Bosquera",
  "telefono": "12000",
  "order_total": 1000,
  "invoiceItems": [
    {
      "id": 7,
      "quantitiy": 10,
      "item": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Costilla de Cerdo Ahumadas Ranchera",
        "description": "Costilla Ahumada, 500 Gramo(s).",
        "price": 30700,
        "img_url": "https://images.rappi.com/products/443434-1594427331970.png",
        "createdAt": "2020-08-07T23:28:03",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-07T23:28:03"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "quantitiy": 10,
      "item": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Hamburguesa Preasada Zenu X 400G",
        "description": "Hamburguesa Preasada Zenu X 400G. 25% Reducido En Sodio, Buena Fuente De Proteína PLU: 802599",
        "price": 12350,
        "img_url": "https://images.rappi.com/products/802599-1594427485528.png",
        "createdAt": "2020-08-07T23:28:03",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-07T23:28:03"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would really appreciate your help, I dare to publish because I have already tried to understand what the problem is and I can not find it

Comment: You can compare your source code with an example here, it has all the types of DB relationships: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa

Comment: I just checked but I can't find one that's ManyToMany of this type.

Comment: Can you show me how you code to for your post request ?

Comment: I have all the information, post request, post response, and all the items that are in stock -> https://pastebin.com/v15UKH3K

Comment: I mean controller/ service for your post request

Comment: post controller https://pastebin.com/MpyMjn8g

Comment: For bidirectional relation it's needed to sync both end, means you have to set `item` field of every `InvoiceItem` then the foreign key will set. That's why I am asking for your service code to know you are doing that or not. You problem specify that may be you are not doing that.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4YragqPh here is Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For bidirectional relation it's needed to sync both end, means you have to set invoice field of every InvoiceItem then the foreign key will set.

```
fun addOrder(invoice: Invoice): ResponseEntity<Invoice> {
   invoice.invoiceItems.forEach { it -> it.invoice= invoice}
   ResponseEntity.ok(parentRepository.save(invoice))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, apparently it has worked, but although I have a doubt, it is necessary to really assign each one in the foreach, does hibernate automatically take care of associating this?

Comment: For foriegn key you have to sync both end, hibernate don't do automatically

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you JSON deserialization is correct ? Without @JsonManagedReference / @JsonBackReference, the bidirectional relation may not be set in InvoiceItem

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice_item")
data class InvoiceItem(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Int? = 0,

    val quantitiy: Int? = 0,

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "invoice_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    val invoice: Invoice? = null,

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    @JsonManagedReference
    val item: Item? = null

)
```

Comment: I just sent an object of type Invoice, and the answer is this https://pastebin.com/tsivFETM I check again in the invoice_id relation, they are still empty and it does not associate the relation

Comment: I have all the information, post request, post response, and all the items that are in stock -> https://pastebin.com/v15UKH3K